# php or javascript Grab next array on button

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, form-post

Pulling simplexml and parsing them into php variables.  I have a form with arrays in them.  I want a button outside the form that will "essentially" go to the same form but with the next array number.  IE:

```
<? 
   if( $xml = simplexml_load_file('my.xml') ) {
       foreach( $xml as $SAVED_EXPORT) {
           $mfg = $SAVED_EXPORT->productmanufacturer;
        }
   }
?>

<form id="myform" method="post" action="coderdb.php">
  <input type="text" value="<? echo $mfg[0] ?>" name="MFG" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I'd like to have a button that says NEXT that when clicked it will pull up the next array ie. `$mfg[1]`.  I believe the page would have to be reloaded which is fine.  I read somewhere I may have to use `$key` but have never used and I am not exactly sure its what I need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some javascript use JQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var array = [];
<? 
    if( $xml = simplexml_load_file('my.xml') ) {
        $i=0;
        foreach( $xml as $SAVED_EXPORT) {
            $mfg = $SAVED_EXPORT->productmanufacturer;
        }
    }
    foreach($mgf as $key=$value) {
        // if $key in not numeric then add iterator for this foreach   
        echo "array[$key]=$value";
    }
?>
        iterator = 0;
        $('#nextExport').click(function(){
            var theInput = $('#setExport');
            // theInput.attr('val',array[iterator]);      
            theInput.val(array[iterator]);
            if(iterator==array.length) { 
                  iterator = -1;
            }
            iterator++; 
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="myform" method="post" action="coderdb.php">
     <input type="text" id="setExport" value="<? echo $mfg[0] ?> name="MFG" />
     <input type="button" id="nextExport" value="Next Export" />
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I hope this helps. if something goes wrong check the syntax , logic is right.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way of keeping track of which array index you are at because as of right now you only have it set to a static number `0`. So if you add a hidden form you can have it post the value that you are currently at and then using PHP you can increment it before displaying the new form. Also your form should point to the PHP document that it is on.

```
<? 
   if( $xml = simplexml_load_file('my.xml') ) {
       foreach( $xml as $SAVED_EXPORT) {
           $mfg = $SAVED_EXPORT->productmanufacturer;
        }
   }
   if(isset($_POST["index"])) $index = $_POST["index"] + 1;
   else $index = 0;
?>

<form id="myform" method="post" action="coderdb.php">
  <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $index ?>" name="index" />
  <input type="text" value="<? echo $mfg[$index] ?>" name="MFG" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```